# Pure function with haskell and database access

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How can it be possible to tell that a function is pure :

- statelessness : given the same parameters, the result is stricly the same (1+2 = 3)
- immutability : the value doesn't change with time

in a data access context ?

Admiting that I have a getAll function that retrieves all the users of a table. This users can vary with time, with add, remove etc...

How can it be possible to make getAll a pure function ?

Comment: To be pure, it must be a function of the table, or of the whole DB.

Comment: What's the actual question? Database access functions in Haskell live in some kind of monad context (IO or otherwise)

Comment: Why would you like to make `getAll` a pure function - knowing that it isn't?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't know enough about lisp to give any information about the situation with respect to that language. I only know there is something out there like typed scheme - but again I don't know enough about the power of its type system.

### How to tell if a function is pure (in a data access context or not)

In haskell you can see/encode information about the purity of a function in its type signature. I would guess the signature of `getAll` would be something like:

```
getAll :: DBConn -> IO Tables
```

here the `IO` marks that the impurity of that function. In haskell this modelling of impurity can be done with `Monads` a general abstraction for situation that appear quite often.

### How to make a function pure?

Now there are Monads you can easily get out of - for example `Maybe` you can use `fromMaybe defaultValue maybeValue` to get rid of the monad context.

`IO` is unlike that - there is no safe way to leave the monad context, notably there is `unsafePerformIO` that can undermine the type system to make the compiler believe "in this situation it is ok to leave `IO`", but unless you really know what you are doing - do not use this!!!

But maybe this is the wrong question - better ask:

### How can I tie pure functions with impure functions together?

Now there are several abstractions that help you tie pure functions in monadic or similar contexts, I recommend to look for `Functor`, `Applicative` and (of course) `Monad` to start with.

For example if you have a function `users :: Table -> [User]` you could use the `Functor` abstraction to tie them together

```
fmap users (getAll conn) (:: IO [User])
```

or equivalently

```
users <$> (getAll conn)
```

note the result of this computation is pure in the `users` part - and gets the indicator for impurity (nameley `IO ..`) "inherited" from the `getAll conn` part.

You can imagine performing the users function inside the `IO` tag.

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` is a really bad idea, in all my years of haskell programming I have never had the need to use it!

Comment: Now, now, it's necessary for some things. The `unamb` stuff needs it, for example (yes, that's "unsafe" to some degree, but there's no getting around it). And while others disagree vehemently, I think it's a perfectly legitimate way to use a Las Vegas (*not* Monte Carlo!) algorithm in a pure context.

Comment: I just wanted to say - in my 7 years of haskell (1/2 year professional) I did not have the need to use `unsafePerformIO` - I have seen it once in production code. But the need never occurred to me - so noone beginning haskell should not need it as well. I know that there are perfectly good reasons for having and using it. But usually if you are asking "should I be using it" this disqualifies you from using it.

Comment: I completely agree. It's a special-purpose tool that should pretty much only be used, with great care, to build new language features or perform crazy optimizations in libraries.